# how to get html source code by usng ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get html source of particulate url by using ajax call,

till I have done,

```
   url: "http://google.com",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            context: document.doctype
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

but in this code its give error,

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.or
```

I want to read html from this call,

How can I achive this , or any other way to do like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the remote resource is not supporting [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)!!!

Comment: i want to get the page source of that url

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are specifying `dataType: "jsonp"` and html is not json. Use `dataType: "text"` instead

Comment: Hello, I want to do in cross domain so i hed add datatype jsonp, now i have replace to text, but when I request to cross domain it will get 200ok responnce but return contant is blank

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ajax to fetch some random content from anywhere in wild world of web... that is one of the reason for implementing Same Origin Policy for ajax requests...

Normal circumstances if a remote resource wants to make itself available across domain in browser environment then they will implement either jsonp or CORS... but both these techniques has to be implemented by the target resource...

In your case it is clear from the error that the remote resource is not implementing jsonp...

One possible solution is to make your web server act like a proxy... ie you sent a request to your server which will sent a request to the remote resource and gets back the remote content then sent it back to the client

Comment: i want to get the page source of that url