# How to get an HTML source page using an HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, html, api, xmlhttprequest

I need to get the HTML source from this website: http://nextbyteindustries.com

It's a redirect to another domain: http://5linx.com

Is there anyway to send a GET request to a website and get the HTML source of the redirected website?

If no, anyway - if I sent a request to this page for example: "http://5linx.com" - how to get its HTML source *while not redirecting*?

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: why not press f12 and see the code and copy it ?

Comment: @Will , no tools - I need to make that using my js codes

Comment: @O.Rares , NOT a solution - I need to access variable websites - my codes will deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through ajax you cant get it. but in other way you can get it

There is a Linux command named **curl**. you can do like

curl http://5linx.com

or you also **wget**

Comment: you cant for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604434/how-to-get-html-source-code-by-usng-ajax-request

Comment: I'm building chrome extension , is there anyway to do this from chrome extension APIs

Answer (score -2):

How will the language be used? For example, in PHP you can do this.

```
<?php
  $page = file_get_contents('http://5linx.com');
  echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: This is not a php question.